# Django and wysiwyg editor (summernote) loads just sometimes

Tags: django, wysiwyg, summernote

I have problem with setting https://github.com/lqez/django-summernote . I followed steps in configuration part and it works great with django runserver - I have summernote in admin page etc. But when I add it to public server, it loads just sometimes.
When I'm pressing F5 in admin page, I can see that sometimes summernote loads and sometimes it doesnt. In nginx-error.log I have this message, when it is not loaded:

```
*ip*  - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /admin/django_summernote/attachment/      HTTP/1.1" 200 3347 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

and I get something like:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin/django_summernote/attachment/ was not found on this server.
```

and this when it is loaded:

```
    *ip* - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip*  - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip*  - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip* - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
*ip*  - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip*  - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip* - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/actions.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip*  - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2384 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
    *ip* - - [20/Feb/2014:12:00:56 +0000] "GET /static/admin/img/icon_searchbox.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://domain.eu/admin/django_summernote/attachment/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

I'm really confused, because it is properly installed and works well with django runserver. And when it is properly loaded, it works just fine. My static dir also has this files:

```
`-- django_summernote
    |-- SOURCE
    |-- django_summernote.css
    |-- jquery.fileupload.js
    |-- jquery.iframe-transport.js
    |-- jquery.ui.widget.js
    |-- lang
    |-- summernote.css
    `-- summernote.min.js
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It must be an debug mode when you're running django project with `runserver`.
If django runs in debug mode, serving static files via `urls.py` works fine. But this doesn't work as expected on `debug=False`.

You have to serve static files via web servers (like nginx) on production phase. Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/